# OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener not getting fired

Tags: android

In `MainActivity` I am registering `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in `onCreate` and UnRegistering in `onDestroy`. Even when i am changing preferences , the Callback is not getting fired in `MainActivity`. I followed other questions on Stack-overflow and Android Documentation, but all those solutions are not working for me.

Actually, i would like to know if we can debug why my callback is not getting called or any other solution that might be helpful.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
ArrayList<String> posterPaths = new ArrayList<>();
private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener preferenceChangeListener =
        new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
                if (key.equals(getString(R.string.pref_order_key))) {
                    fetchImagesIfOnline();
                }
            }
        };



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main,menu);
    return true;
}

 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    preferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Settings.class));
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceChangeListener);


    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), posterPaths);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.movie_grid);
    gridview.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String image = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent movieDetailsIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MovieDetails.class);
            movieDetailsIntent.putExtra("image",(String) imageAdapter.getItem(position));
            startActivity(movieDetailsIntent);
        }
    });

    fetchImagesIfOnline();
}
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}

public void fetchImagesIfOnline() {
    if (isOnline())
    {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String sortOrder = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.pref_order_key),getString(R.string.pref_order_toprated));
        Log.d("DEBUG","Sort order is " + sortOrder);
        DownloadTask downloadTask;
        downloadTask = new DownloadTask(imageAdapter,posterPaths);
        downloadTask.execute(sortOrder);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(View parent, String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    return super.onCreateView(parent, name, context, attrs);
}
```

}

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: I have posted code for `MainActivity` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `onCreate` you register your listener

```
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

you can unregister it on `onDistry`

if you do it like this , this should work !

```
listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
      public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
        // your code
      }
    };

    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
```

Comment: Actually i did the same thing, but its not getting invoked. When i change preferences, the call back in `SettingsActivity` is getting invoked, but not the one in `MainActivity`.

Comment: where is your listener ?

Comment: I have declared in the `MainActivity` as preferenceChangeListener, you can see it on line number 5 in above code posted.

Comment: you unregistered in on the on create why i think thats the issue

Comment: you can always accept an answer if its right as a thanks :)